# How to close scanner object when it is called outside of the enclosing class?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

Let's say I have a custom reader object that throws exception:

```
public StationReader {

    public StationReader(String inFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inFile);

        while (scan.hasNextLine() {
            // blah blah blah
        }

        // Finish scanning
        scan.close();       
    }
}
```

And I call the StationReader in another class, Tester:

```
public Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            StationReader sReader = new StationReader("i_hate_csv.csv");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found arggghhhhhh");
        } finally {
            // HOW TO CLOSE SCANNER HERE??
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's imagine that whilst scanning through the lines, an exception is thrown, so `scan.close()` is never called.

How do I close the scanner object then in this case?

Comment: Use a `try-with-resources` or make the `StationReader` `Closable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the read process in a [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), but don't catch any of the exceptions, simply let them be passed back to the caller, for example...

```
public class CustomReader {

    public CustomReader(String inFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(inFile)) {
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                // blah blah blah
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `try-with-resource` statement will automatically close the resource when the code exists the `try` block

*fyi: `finally` use to be used for this, but when you have multiple resources, it becomes messy. All hail `try-with-resources`*

Comment: would you say because of that it's better to just catch the exceptions instead of throwing them?

Comment: @doctopus I think it's better to allow the exception to be bubbled to the caller, otherwise they might try to continue to interact with the object, unaware that something has gone wrong - but that's my opinion ;)